# What "improvements in technology" allowed the primary mirror of RST (WFIRST) to be less than 1/4 the weight of Hubble's?

Tags: space-telescope, hubble, nancy-grace-roman-space-telescope

The recent NASA press release [Primary Mirror for NASA’s Roman Space Telescope Completed](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2020/primary-mirror-for-nasas-roman-space-telescope-completed) states:

> While it’s the same size as the Hubble Space Telescope’s main mirror, it is less than one-fourth the weight. Roman’s mirror weighs only 410 pounds (186 kilograms) thanks to major improvements in technology.

What are the "major improvements in technology" that would allow for such a drastic reduction in weight?

Comment: *Interesting question!* I was going to guess that they used silicon carbide [like these](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/34773/7982) instead of glass, but the article says they used glass.

Comment: Every article I read parrots that exact same phrase, but never gives any detail. Annoying.

Comment: @OrganicMarble there are some images [here](https://www.harris.com/solution/nancy-grace-roman-space-telescope). It's a complicated [Three-mirror anastigmat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-mirror_anastigmat) and so 1) doesn't look at all like Hubble, 2) has two more *pretty big* mirrors, 3) has a *giant hole* in the primary, and (4?) I don't know but there might be actuators in one of the other elements to actively compensate for small thermal drifts. Until recently it was called WFIRST so that may be a helpful search term.

Comment: A more fair, or at least interesting comparison would be the *payload mass* of RTS vs HST. RTS's telescope itself may not be lighter than HST's telescope for example.

Comment: [The Nancy Roman Telescope has reached another milestone in its development. NASA has announced that the space telescope’s primary mirror is now complete. The 2.4 meter (7.9 ft) mirror took less time to develop than other mirrors because it wasn’t built from scratch. It’s a re-shaped and re-surfaced mirror that came from the National Reconnaissance Office.](https://www.universetoday.com/147664/nancy-roman-telescopes-primary-2-4-meter-mirror-is-ready/) which links to [NRO gives NASA two hand-me-down telescopes](https://www.planetary.org/articles/nasa-gets-two-hand-me-down)

Comment: @OrganicMarble - That this satellite is an NRO hand-me-down may well explain why details are so hard to find. As I've said before, the US Department of Defense would classify $F=ma$ as TS/NOFORN if they had their druthers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WFIRST stands for Wide Field Infrared Survey Telescope. The fabrication technologies used to construct the PM blank include abrasive water jets to reduce the core's weight and a proprietary glass-to-glass fusing technology to bond the faceplates to the core. HST had much thicker face plates and thicker ribs in the core.

Comment: Interesting!  Have you found any sources that go more into depth on this?

Comment: PM = primary mirror, since you only use it once the space saved by using an acronym is small and the possibilities that readers will not recognize it larger. Maybe just spell it out?